# how to use loop inside query on firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to use loop inside query?

```
  Future<void> addServiceConfig(String uid, List<ServiceConfigModel> model) {
    _db.collection('users').document(uid).updateData({
      'businessDetails':{
        'serviceConfig':FieldValue.arrayUnion([
          {
            for(int i = 0;i <model.length;i++){
              if (model[i].inShop != null) 'inShop': model[i].inShop,
              if (model[i].inShopAndClientLocation != null)
                'inShopAndClientLocation': model[i].inShopAndClientLocation,
              if (model[i].clientLocation != null)
                'clientLocation': model[i].clientLocation,
              'serviceLocations': model[i].serviceLocations,
              'subCategoryId': model[i].subCategoryId
            }
        }
        ])
      }
    });
  }
```

**I got this error:**

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of '_CompactLinkedHashSet>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a loop (or many other statements) inside an expression, like the value of a field. One solution is to pull construct the value outside of the `update()` all and then pass it in:

```
//var config = new Map()
```

var result = new List();

```
for(int i = 0;i < model.length; i++){
  var config = new Map();
  if (model[i].inShop != null) config['inShop'] = model[i].inShop;
  if (model[i].inShopAndClientLocation != null) 
    config['inShopAndClientLocation'] = model[i].inShopAndClientLocation;
  if (model[i].clientLocation != null) 
    config['clientLocation'] = model[i].clientLocation;
  config['serviceLocations'] = model[i].serviceLocations,
  config['subCategoryId'] = model[i].subCategoryId;
 result.add(config);
}

_db.collection('users').document(uid).updateData({
  'businessDetails':{
    'serviceConfig': FieldValue.arrayUnion(result)
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks. I tried it. but only insert 1 value to database.. model length is 3. but insert only 1 to database

Comment: I think issue is, `config` variable is not a list of map